# How to setup Chef management console for Chef Server(existing one spun up using AWS OpsWorks)

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

This is my first time working with AWS OpsWorks.

I spun up a AWS OpsWorks instance(consists of Chef Automate and Chef server). I have an existing chef server URL mentioned in my knife.rb file - "https://chef-automate-xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.opsworks-cm.io/organizations/default". I need to setup a chef management console for the chef server to manage my nodes, granting access to users etc.

How do I setup a chef management console for the above specified chef-server?

Can someone please give me an overview of the setup? Or share a link to the documentation that might be of use.

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 1):

If you have [purchased](https://www.chef.io/pricing/) Chef Automate, you can install Chef Management Console on your node with the following commands:

```
chef-server-ctl install chef-manage

chef-server-ctl reconfigure

chef-manage-ctl reconfigure
```

You can find more installation information by following the chef server installation [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html#standalone).